# Karate - How to terminate driver instance when mixed with robot?

Tags: karate

I have a test that combines the use of a *driver* and *robot*. However, I need to terminate the *driver* instance before invoking *robot*. Even if I use the explicit *driver.close()*, the instance remains active. Here's an example (*create-input.feature* invokes the *driver*):

```
Feature: mixing driver and robot

Background:
    * call read('../../../../actions/workflow/general/create-input.feature')  {sample-id: sampleId}
    * configure afterScenario = function(){ karate.call('../../../../actions/auth/signout.feature'); }

Scenario: terminate driver before invoking robot
    * print '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>BEFORE CLOSE>>>>>>>>>>>>>>', driver
    * driver.close()
    * print '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>AFTER CLOSE>>>>>>>>>>>>>>', driver
    * robot { window: '#(windowName)', fork: '#(appPath)', retryCount:  '#(retryCount)', autoClose:  '#(autoClose)', highlight: '#(highlight)', highlightDuration: '#(highlightDuration)' }
    * window(windowName)
    * call read('../../../../actions/auth/signin.feature')
```

After the explicit close, the *driver* instance remains active:

```
INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>BEFORE CLOSE>>>>>>>>>>>>>> com.intuit.karate.driver.chrome.Chrome@d3324b
09:47:24.064 [main]  DEBUG c.intuit.karate.driver.DriverOptions - >> {"id":83,"method":"Page.close"}
09:47:24.069 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1]  DEBUG c.intuit.karate.driver.DriverOptions - << {"id":83,"result":{}}
09:47:24.072 [main]  INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>AFTER CLOSE>>>>>>>>>>>>>> com.intuit.karate.driver.chrome.Chrome@d3324b
```

And when the *robot* logic is reached, it throws an error:

```
* window(windowName)
>>>> js failed:
01: window(windowName)
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "window" is not defined
- <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)

09:47:27.917 [main]  DEBUG c.intuit.karate.driver.DriverOptions - >> {"id":84,"method":"Page.captureScreenshot"}
09:47:57.919 [main]  ERROR c.intuit.karate.driver.DriverOptions - << timed out after milliseconds: 30000 - [id: 84, method: Page.captureScreenshot]
* window(windowName)
scenario [run] failed
failed to get reply for: [id: 84, method: Page.captureScreenshot]
09:47:58.056 [main]  WARN  com.intuit.karate - 'driver' is active, use 'robot.' prefix for robot methods
```

I realize that I need to prepend the *window()* method with *robot* to make it work, but I'd prefer to just terminate the *driver* instance prior to invoking *robot*. Reason being is that I later call other features with assertions specific to *robot* and with the *driver* still being active, it causes further issues.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `driver.quit()` ? https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#quit

If that doesn't work (it should !) you can submit an issue, but I insist that you provide a way to replicate: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

As a workaround - you could experiment if [using the Java API directly](https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1353969718730788865) gives you the control you need: https://github.com/intuit/karate#java-api

Answer (score 1):

As always, thanks Peter for a prompt response and turnaround. I tested it with your [fix](https://github.com/intuit/karate/commit/f29ad4058660de2935a8332b658cd44e2cc8dabb) applied and it works as expected. Following is the simplified test I used:

```
Feature: mixing driver and robot

Background:
  * configure driver = { type: 'chrome', showDriverLog: true }

Scenario: terminate driver before invoking robot
  * driver 'https://google.com'
  * input("input[name=q]", 'karate dsl')
  * submit().click("input[name=btnI]")
  * waitForUrl('https://github.com/intuit/karate')
  * quit()

  * robot { window: 'Calculator', fork: 'calc', highlight: true, highlightDuration: 500 }
  * click('Clear')
  * click('One')
  * click('Plus')
  * click('Two')
  * click('Equals')
  * match locate('#CalculatorResults').name == 'Display is 3'
  * screenshot()
  * click('Close Calculator')
```