Switch to already open web application after interacting with desktop app in karate framework
Steps-wise details

Desktop app loaded and verified login
Web application is loaded in the browser and login into the application
Now Switch the user interaction to Desktop app
Now again switch the user interaction to already opened Web application
Facing difficult in framing the code for jumping from step 3rd to step 4
driver.switch(OriginalWindow) fails
and

niether print or karate.log is working
Eclipse SDK
Version 2024-06(4.32)
Expected how write code to switch from the Desktop app to already open Web app window
and
print and karate.log to work
Fails with below error
01: driver.switch(originalWindow)
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: invokeMember (switch) on com.intuit.karate.driver.chrome.Chrome failed due to: Unknown identifier: switch

.:program(Unnamed:1)


if you mean robot, refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67145842/143475 - and depending on which was started first - you may need to use driver. or robot. - refer https://stackoverflow.com/q/67067119/143475

Thanks @PeterThomas for your response. The desktop app automating Sikuli is used  and web automation karate framework. Switching to web app in the browser From desktop app user interaction is the challenge

I can't help more than this to be honest, lets home someone else has some ideas
